# JavaScript event handler/listener for C# event

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, uwp, event-handling

I am writing a application in JavaScript(UWP). I am using a Windows Run time Component written in C# to handle all network traffic for my application. I have made events so that when i receive data from the server i invoke an event.

Now i want to listen to this event from a JavaScript file, and in Visual Studio it looks to work fine(see image link (1)), but when i compile with node.js i get errors(see image link (2)).

```
 //Delegating
public delegate void AssistResponseDelegate(AssistResponse response);
 //Creating the event
public event AssistResponseDelegate AssistResponseReceived;
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
//In my JS file...

//Assigning a listener, n_manager being a class.
n_manager.assistresponsereceived = function (response) {            
      console.log("Listener called");                     //debug
      //call function to handle the response further
```

}

So, whats wierd is that in Visual Studio it seems to work fine calling and assigning the listeners [When hoovering my mouse over the JS code for calling/assigning the listener it understands that it is c# code and seems to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmGDc.png), but when i compile my solution with Node.js i get an error saying that [the Network is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NCS9.png). So my problem is with node.js not being able to read the c# namespace?

Comment: `AssistResponseReceived?.Invoke(ar); ` are you sure this is an ["event"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx)?  Please upload more relative code snippet. For example, the code snippet you declare the event, the code snippet about the `AssistResponseReceived` and `AssistResponseDelegate`.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT Thanks for your comment, i have edited my question to try and give you more information and code as you asked.

Comment: How you compile your solution with node.js? Please provide the [mcve] and the reproduce steps to let us have a testing on our side

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. What happens is when webpack compiles the bundle.js file it does not compile the C# components so it does not have the reference to the objects I am trying to access. When I run the application as an UWP application, it works fine.